# Changing ImageView source while populating a ListView

Tags: java, android

There are already a few questions on this subject, but I can't find what's wrong. I have a ListView with an ImageView and a TextView. The listview uses item_layout.xlm, wich contains both elements.

I can populate the TextView in the ListView with an ArrayAdapter, but I get a NullPointerException when trying to change the source of the ImageView.

```
 private void populateListViewLongFronde() {

        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllDifEntries("long_fronde");
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                R.layout.item_layout,
                R.id.textView3,
                DBAdapter.AlResults );

        myList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.deltoide);

    }
```

And this is the Logcat:

```
09-15 02:38:50.319    1769-1769/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gobtron.database_test/com.gobtron.database_test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.gobtron.database_test.MainActivity.populateListViewLongFronde(MainActivity.java:119)
            at com.gobtron.database_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ArrayAdapter to store data for both ImageView and TextView. You need to implement your own list adapter, and you probably want to extend BaseAdapter. Your code gives you null pointer probably because you can't access list view elements by using findViewByID in the activity, and you shouldn't anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because the ImageView is in the item_layout.xml,you should do like that:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
    ImageView imgView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
```